# Update or append a TextView from a Broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android

I am trying to append/update information in a `TextView` from a `BroadcastReceiver`.  What would be the right way to do this?  I have put in in my Manifest to register the phone state:

```
    <receiver android:name="RingTypeBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name= "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">               </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Next I want to grab the phone state that the receiver picked up, increment a counter.  I want to be able to append/update this information on a `textview` called `txtResults` that I have on my `Activity`.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RingTypeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

int counterCall = 0;
int counterIdleOrOffHook = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
    String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        counterCall = counterCall + 1;
    }
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        counterIdleOrOffHook = counterIdleOrOffHook + 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You might have to save the value in a db or in sharedpreferences and display the value in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your broadcast receiver inside your activity that is setting the text. (sub class it)

Here is an untested example. It might need slight modification, but I have done something like this before so it will work.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtResults;

....do activity stuff....

public static class RingTypeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

int counterCall = 0;
int counterIdleOrOffHook = 0;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
     String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        counterCall = counterCall + 1;
    }
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        counterIdleOrOffHook = counterIdleOrOffHook + 1;
    }

   //here you can set your text view. But check that it is not null first! 
   if(txtResults != null){
       txtResults.setText("whatever");
   }
  }
}
```

Then, update your Manifest so it will point to the Broadcast receiver:

```
 <receiver android:name="YourActivity$RingTypeBroadcastReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
 </receiver>
```

As you can see, you have your Activity followed by a `$` then your broadcast receiver. That tells the manifest to look *inside* your activity.

Also note: If your activity is in a package below your app's package name (`com.example.yourapp`) you will need to add that to your manifest. So for instance, if your activity was in `com.example.yourapp/activity` you would need to change the name in the manifest to `.activity.YourActivity$RingTypeBroadcastReceiver`. It is just everything after your apps package name, starting with `.`.

Comment: Tried the code you provided but no luck.  You still need to add the receiver filter into the Manifest correct?  I am assuming you would put the `RingTypeBroadcastReceiver` as the name vice the Activity class `YourActivity`?

Comment: Yes, still put it inside your manifest. And keep your activity the same as it was. Just put the receiver inside your activity. Be sure your broadcastReceiver is static class.

Comment: _"I am assuming you would put the RingTypeBroadcastReceiver as the name vice the Activity class YourActivity"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: `<receiver android:name="RingTypeBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: When I run it, I get the following error when the event is triggered. "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.ringtype.RingTypeBroadcastReceiver: ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class.....

Comment: Ah, yeah. So since your broadcast receiver is a sub class, you will need to change your manifest slightly. See my update.